# Добавление элемента в конец двусвязного списка

Tags: c++, списки, двусвязный-список

Здравствуйте, не полностью понял как добавлять элементы в двусвязный список. Здесь я добавил в начало списка. 
Как сделать добавление в конец списка?

```
    void plus (float av_point, int num, string surn){
    Students *tmp=new Students;
    tmp->Next=NULL;
    tmp->average_point=av_point;
    tmp->number=num;
    tmp->surname=surn;
    if (head!=NULL){
        tmp->Prev=tail;
        tail->Next=tmp;
        tail=tmp;
    }
    else{
        tmp->Prev=NULL;
        head=tail=tmp;
    }
}
```

Как сделать добавление в конец списка? Имеется структура такого типа.

```
struct Students{
string surname;
int number;
float average_point;
string study; 
Students *Next, *Prev;
```

Comment: По сути нам нужно заменить Next и head на Prev и tail?

Comment: "Здесь я добавил в начало списка"? Где "здесь"? В приведенном коде делается добавление в конец списка. Что такое "здесь" тогда?

Answer (score 1):

При добавлении нового элемента в конец связного списка необходимо чтобы:
1. Старый конец списка следующим у нового конца списка (а у старого конца списка новый - предыдущим).
2. Предыдущего элемента у нового конца списка не было.
3. Обновилась информация о новом конце списка

```
tmp->Next = tail; //Новый хвост смотрит на старый
tmp->Prev = null; //Новый хвост ни на что не оборачивается
tail->Prev = tmp; //Старый хвост оборачивается на новый
tail = tmp; //Запоминаем указатель на новый хвост
```

В случае, если Вы хотите реализовать замкнутый связный список - в `tmp->Prev`
необходимо поместить head, а в head->Next, соответственно, tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал вам при изучении какой-либо структуры данных сначала нарисовать её и рассмотреть как это выглядит все на бумаге (но это ИМХО, мне так проще).
А вообще вот:

```
n = new Node(...);
tail->next = n;
tail->next->prev = tail;
tail = n;
```

если head != nullptr;